# How do I find the "file path" for a file in an AWS s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to find the file in an s3 bucket using it's file path. How would I find that file path? Can I query a bucket for a particular file?

Comment: What do you mean by "query a bucket for a particular file"? What are you wanting to use for the search (eg filename, size, date)? If it's the filename, how are you getting the filename? Objects in Amazon S3 have a `Key`, which is the full filename including the path, so it's unusual to only have the 'filename' portion.

Answer (score 2):

You can test for the presence of an object in a bucket using the [HeadObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_HeadObject.html) API. You would supply the bucket name and the object's key to that API.

To get a list of all objects under a bucket, you can use the [ListObjectsV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) API. You would supply the bucket name and an optional key prefix to that API.

Both are available in your AWS SDK of choice under a similar name, such as `headObject` or `head_object`.

Answer (score 0):

Objects in S3 are stored by `key`. Often the key includes slashes, which function like path separators, but they really aren't. So to get a particular file you would need to include the full key ("path" and name).